# Jquery form validation. Disable input until other input validates

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form with 2 input fields and i want the second input field to remain disabled until the first field is valid.

It works but not in the way i expect.  What happens is if the first field validates, the second field is enabled but if i click in the second field, it disables again.  It will only work if i use the tab key

How can i get the form to work how i expect?

```
    $("#bin").prop('disabled', true);
    $('#prefix').addClass('field_disabled');
    $('span').addClass('field_disabled');

    $('#toteform').bind('change keyup', function() {
        if($(this).validate().checkForm()) {
            $('#prefix').removeClass('field_disabled');
            $('span').removeClass('field_disabled');
            $('#bin').removeClass('field_disabled').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {    
            $('#prefix').addClass('field_disabled');
            $('span').addClass('field_disabled');
            $('#bin').addClass('field_disabled').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });

    $('#form_result').hide();   

    // validate the comment form when it is submitted
    $("#toteform").validate({
        errorLabelContainer: '#errors',
        rules: {
            tote: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                minlength: 4
            },
            bin: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and html

```
<div id="main_div" class="container frame" style="text-align:center;">
        <div id="msgcontainer">
            <div id="errors"></div>
            <div id="form_result">Tote successfully added!!</div>
        </div>
        <form id="toteform" method="post" action="">
            <p><label>Tote Number:</label>
            <input type="text" name="tote" id="tote" maxlength="4"  autocomplete="off" autofocus tabindex="1" /></p>
            <p><label>Bin Number:</label></p>
            <div id="prefix"><span>J</span><input type="text" name="bin" id="bin" maxlength="4"  autocomplete="off" tabindex="2"  /></div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Submit tote number"  tabindex="3" />
        </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What you should really do is split this into two different pages.

Answer (score 0):

not seeing the HTML is hard, but take a look at this simple example. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XhcDX/)
basically I have 2 inputs:

```
<input type="text" id="form_1" placeholder="here">
<input type="text" id="form_2" placeholder="disable" class="not_valid" disabled>
```

And a Jquery call (like yours except for the validation logic)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#form_1').bind('change keyup', function() {
     // Your validation
     var length_var = $(this).val().length;
     if(length_var > 3) {
         $('#form_2').removeAttr('disabled');     
     } else {
     }
   });
});
```

cheers

Comment: This is really nice but ideally if the users removes anything from the first field after it validates the second field won't disable

Comment: This was just the concept not the solution for all the cases.